# Xbee pro s2c 2.4 ghz 10dbi Antenna and its effect

Tags: rf, electromagnetism, xbee, pcb-antenna, telecommunications

Just wondreing  how to increase the range/distance of communication between two xbee modules operating in API mode,

we are considering to replace the 2.4 ghz antenna of 5dbi gain with 10dbi high gain antenna, does it work and fit into our need, the only term i cannot understand is the power requirements of the antenna.

Does antennas draw more power if their gain is higher? And also the xbee pro s2c module power is limited to 10mw as per the digi website.

Answer (score 1):

*Does antennas draw more power if their gain is higher?* No, the power is set by the RF module, the antenna gets a certain amount of RF power and that's it.

That "gain" rating is deceptive as it is not really gain in all directions. [Read this.](https://www.wirelesshack.org/how-much-of-a-gain-does-a-9dbi-wifi-antenna-make-over-a-5dbi-antenna.html) A higher gain antenna will just **direct** the power (and be more sensitive) in certain directions. It will transmit **less** power and be **less** sensitive in other directions.

So you can use "high gain" antennas to increase the range **but** you will have to make them "see" each other. And if one of the devices is not in a fixed position, overall range might end up being less than what you had.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information,as mentioned above that the high gain antennas will only direct the power in certain directions, Is there any mechanism is available to find out how the radiation pattern of that antenna is? And connecting the coax extension to the antenna may also have some effect on the signal loss.i guess?

Comment: *Is there any mechanism is available to find out how the radiation pattern of that antenna is?* Sure, read the datasheet of the antenna. You could also measure it but that requires very expensive equipment. Yes the Coax cable can also attenuates the signal a lot, use the wrong cable and the signal will be lost (almost). So use the right type and keep the cables short (a couple of cm).